# Many to Many Relationship Query in Android Room always returns only one result

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-room

I try to query the database so for a certain manufacturer, it returns a set of products. The relationship between this table is many to many and i use a junction table for these. But if I try to set up the query in Room it always returns only one product for that manufacturer. I want ALL the products for the manufacturer with the given id.

Here's the **parent** table:

```
@Entity(tableName = "manufacturer")
public class ManufacturerEntry {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

Here's the **child** table:

```
@Entity(tableName = "product")
public class ProductEntry {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String shoeType;
    private String name;
}
```

Here's the **junction** table:

```
@Entity(tableName = "bom", foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(entity = ManufacturerEntry.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "manufacturerId"),
        @ForeignKey(entity = ProductEntry.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "productId")}, primaryKeys = {"productId", "manufacturerId"})
public class BomEntry {
    private int productId;
    private int manufacturerId;
}
```

Here's the relationship class:

```
public class ManufacturerWithProducts {
    @Embedded
    public ManufacturerEntry manufacturerEntry;
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "id",
            entityColumn = "id",
            associateBy = @Junction(value = BomEntry.class, parentColumn="manufacturerId", entityColumn = "productId")
    )
    public List<ProductEntry> productEntryList;
}
```

Finally, the DAO interface:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM manufacturer WHERE id = :id")
LiveData<List<ManufacturerWithProducts>> loadManufacturerWithProducts(int id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used a regular SQL query on top of a DAO and built a separate return object for that query.

```
public class ManufacturerAndProductNames {
    public String manufacturerName;
    public String productName;
}
```